# When i try find element by class it doesn't work (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i have this:

```
from telnetlib import EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

PATH = "hidden"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(
    "hidden")

searchUserName = driver.find_element_by_id("hidden")
searchUserName.send_keys("hidden")
searchUserName.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

searchPassword = driver.find_element_by_id("hidden")
searchPassword.send_keys("hidden")
searchPassword.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "span.myfrog-circle overdue"))
    )
    print(wait.text)
except:
    driver.quit()
```

So it always closes because it can't find the element but on the website this is what the source code is:
`<span class="myfrog-circle overdue">22</span>`

the error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".myfrog-circle overdue"}`

Comment: Because there is no class named ```span.myfrog-circle overdue```. Also, how are we supposed to debug if you change URL to hidden

Comment: @YashShah i changed it to myfrog-circle overdue and also i changed it because you have to login into the website

Comment: @Oli   In that case add the relevant element html code to the post so that we can debug

Comment: @Dev @Yash Shah
```<li class="" data-action="assignments" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="MyFrog">
        <span class="myfrog-circle overdue">22</span>
    </li>```

Answer (score 0):

The class will only work with a single class name in it. in your case you have two classes inside tag.

```
<span class="myfrog-circle overdue">22</span>
```

try with the below code

css :: `.myfrog-circle .overdue`

XPATH : - `//span[@class='myfrog-circle overdue']`

Comment: i don't get what you mean by that i have this now:

```try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='myfrog-circle overdue']"))
    )```

Comment: this work for u ?:- EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='myfrog-circle overdue']"))

Comment: no it just prints a line and closes heres the html
```<li class="" data-action="assignments" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="MyFrog">
        <span class="myfrog-circle overdue">22</span>
    </li>```

Answer (score 0):

Compound classes need a . in between and try getting innerhtml instead of .text.

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.myfrog-circle.overdue"))
    )
    print(wait.text)
    print(wait.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
except:
    driver.quit()
```